# Selenium IDE unable to inspect disabled input text field in contextmenu

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

Selenium IDE unable to inspect disabled input text field in contextmenu 
When i Right click on disabled text-field in Firefox it doesn't show available Commands. But when i Right click other element and again Right click the disabled element, it shows previous element xpath.

please help me regarding the issue.

[Initially On page load and without clicking any element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jir8A.png)

[After clicking another element shows false xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6M8MJ.png)

Comment: it sounds like your page might be using javascript to dynamically change the dom & these specific elements.

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm trying a simple html page. You can try it here.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_disabled

first right click on disabled input field.
Next right click on enabled input field.
Again right click on disabled input field.

Observe the difference.

Comment: Which firefox version and selenium ide version you are using?

Comment: Ok. This looks like it might be a bug with the IDE in that it can keep the enabled element values in the context menu. However you should still be able to "inspect" the element. Meanwhile there are other ways to get the xpath of an element. Using firebug is one way.

Comment: Thank You DMart, i know the possible ways to get the xpath of that element, but i'm trying to change the internal code of selenium IDE to make it work. Help me on that if possible and thanks in advance.

Comment: It's firefox 42 and Selenium IDE 2.9.1  @Sudharsan Srinivasan

Comment: Feel free to contribute to the code: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/ide

You could also file an issue there to hope it gets worked on.